# Excel Custom Formatting and/or Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

I have a list of numbers for a client like below:

```
8481.80.9005
8481.80.9005    
8413309090
8413309090
```

The first two numbers exhibit the correct formatting, per the client. Is there a formula and/or custom formatting that I can use to make all numbers uniformly the correct format?

Note - all numbers are 10 digits with periods after the fourth and sixth digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a custom format is that Excel will read the number as a whole number and any attempt at putting in the `.`, if your local settings are set to the `.` being the decimal separator, is that it will try to put it at the end.

So we need to first make it a string with some other separator and then do a substitute.

The following formula does that:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-0000"),"-",".")
```

[image]

Comment: Would 0000-00-0000 be preferable in case there were leading zeroes?

Comment: Yes, yes it would. @TomSharpe

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm going to be shot down on this one, but couldn't see why you can't do

```
0000\.00\.0000
```

in custom formatting

Comment: Why would you be shot down.  I like it better than mine.  I forgot you can escape the `.` as text using `\`.

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised. Thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both great answers.